# Find collection names in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

There are 20 different collections in my mongodb, and the count might increase to much more.

Is there a way to find out list of collection name that start with lets say "type_"? If not, then is there a way to execute some query against a collection whose name starts with "type_" ?

To my knowledge `db.getCollectionNames()` cannot be used it returns all collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function (c) { return c.indexOf('type_') == 0; })
```

It might be possible in 3.0 to do this without a function, see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/listCollections/#dbcmd.listCollections)